# Make SQL*Plus script quit

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I have a few SQL*Plus scripts in a directory that I would like to run automatically using powershell. I can read the directory and but when I tried to execute the script, the scripts terminated but did not quit powershell and go to the next one.

How do I make powershell quit SQL*Plus and go to the next script automatically without me modifying the scripts by explicitly adding a quit at the end of each script?

Below is the illustrated powershell script in its simplest form

```
$Filename=Get-childitem "D:\test\TestSQL" -Filter *.sql | Select -ExpandProperty name
foreach ($f in $Filename)
{
  sqlplus -L -S <username>/<password>@<sid> @$f
}
```

The directory can theoretically contain hundreds of scripts and it is not feasible to add quit command in each script. I would like to force SQL*Plus to quit after completing each script and move on to the next one.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: fyi, "PL/SQL", "SQL" and "SQL\*Plus" are three different things. I think you mean SQL\*Plus which is the command-line tool for running queries etc.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: thank you for clarifying the terminology. I am pretty new to oracle and thought PL/SQL and SQL Plus are identical stuff. I will correct the wording to avoid confusion. Yes, from what you are saying, it seems SQL*Plus is more proper. Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps you could build a temporary SQL\*Plus script on the fly which calls each .sql script and then exits at the end. It could even add some value by printing the filenames and timestamps.

Comment: Actually I found a better approach on https://serverfault.com/q/87035/352734 - just added answer. Nice question by the way.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: Building a script to run a script works too but your suggested approach is definitely cleaner and better. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the word `exit` into the SQL*Plus command line. For example, if `demo.sql` consists of this:

```
prompt This is my demo script
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
echo exit | sqlplus william/w @demo.sql
```

Output:

```
Y:\SQL>echo exit | sqlplus william/w @demo.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Jan 13 10:47:13 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Jan 13 2019 10:46:03 +00:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production


This is my demo script
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Y:\SQL>
```

Or using the `-s` (silent) option to suppress banners etc:

```
Y:\SQL>echo exit | sqlplus -s william/w @demo.sql

This is my demo script

Y:\SQL>
```

Tested with SQL*Plus 12.2 on Windows 10.

(From https://serverfault.com/q/87035/352734 - turns out it works in both Windows and Linux.)

You could also look at options for avoiding handling usernames and passwords e.g. here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109170/103604

Comment: Your suggestion works like a charm.. clean and efficient. Thank you!

Comment: Actually it appears that piping anything into SQL\*Plus on Windows causes it to exit, e.g. `echo set time on | sqlplus un/pw@db`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar plsql but I gather that sqlplus is an exe that executes plsql scripts. If PowerShell is not continuing to the next script it is because sqlplus is not exiting. A little googling suggests that the proper way to end a pssql script is to put a single forward slash on the last line:

```
/
```

From what I understand this tells sqlplus to execute everything above, without it sqlplus will not terminate.

You say:

> it is not feasible to add quit command in each script

But as far as I can tell that is exactly what you have to do.

Luckily PowerShell can help with that too. Just navigate to the directory containing the scripts and execute the following:

```
dir *.sql | add-content -value "/"
```

Comment: Thank you, Jason. Will give it a swirl on Monday and let you know. Will mark your response as answer to make it easy for others to refer to should they have the same issue.

Comment: A missing `/` can sometimes be an issue, but adding one won't make SQL\*Plus quit after the last command. It's an interactive prompt, like `telnet` or `ftp` and you have to tell it to quit.

Comment: @Jason Boyd: Thank you. Your suggestion works although it did alter the script but it works! Thank you so much!!